# ZF2 - Protect form elements

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

I have a form with various form elements. In Create mode all elements must editable but in Edit mode i need to lock certain elements.

I tried to set attributes "readonly" or "disabled" and it works in Browser view. But when the user manipulate the POST-request with e.g. Webdeveloper tools (Forms->Enable Form Fields) in FireFox or other, then the values are accepted from zend form.

How can i safe protect/lock form elements?

Comment: You will need to validate the form data instead of blindly accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not modificate your entity / model with the posted data that you don't need. For this thing a function like `$myModel->populate($request->getPost())` may not be the best approach. Rather write yourself a function like `$myModel->populateForEdit($request->getPost())` in which you only modify the fields that are allowed to be modified on a certain action.

Always remember: any user can send you ANY data he wants. It's up to you to filter the data before populating your models!

Comment: Interrestin approach. I use Doctrine Hydrator in my form: $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineEntity($em))->setObject(new MyEntity()); Any suggestions how can i customize this?

Comment: Hmmm, a weird way would be to have two entities. `$e1 //fetched from DB (uneditted)` and `$e2 //the entity that is posted to you from form` - now for each field you want to modify `$e1->setField($e2->getField())` - but doctrine itself may have some solution for such cases, i'm not that familiar with it yet